# Center Vertical and Horizontal TextView in ScrollView Android XML

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview

I have one application which have TextView in ScrollView. I want arrange it as center in Horizontal and Vertical. I have tried many option like marginTop, marginBottom, paddingTop, paddingBottom but I have not found it working. Currently its hiding my first one two line from top, if I make some changes and its showing all lines clear, but than its not showing in center vertically and horizontally.
What Should I do for make it vertically and Horizontally center ?

My XML is included here.

Thanks

```html
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="In order to succeed ..."
                android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If your textview is bigger (taller) than your viewport (height), what behaviour do you expect from it being centred in the ScrollView?

Comment: yes.....I need it in center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use     **android:fillViewport="true"** in scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@color/red"
android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow">
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/quote"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="In order to succeed ..."
    android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks Boss....You have saved my lot of time. Its working awesome !! Thanks Again Dude !!

Comment: do you really think `fillviewport="true"` is the only change? no other change?

Comment: Yeah `android:fillViewport="true"` did the trick but in this answer `ScrollView` height should be `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to xml:

> android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="In order to succeed ..."
            android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Height of `ScrollView` should be `match_parent`
2. Replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout`
3. `Textview` should have `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

So your final changes will be

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
>
```

Your `RelativeLayout`

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >
```

And finally `TextView`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ...
            ...
/>
```

Comment: We should have use `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView` then no need of `RelativeLayout or (centerInParent)`

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan oh realy? copy his whole code and paste it, just put `android:fillViewport="true"` in `scrollview`, it will not work

Comment: I tried it without `android:fillViewport="true"` your code will not work try your self

Comment: check accepted answer, copy paste it, it will not work @ZubairAhmadKhan

Comment: Yeah I checked it In the accepted answer `ScrollView` height should be `match_parent` in order to take affect on `TextView`. I also commented same in accepted answer

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan but no need of fillviewport, you can do it without that also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99086/discussion-between-zubair-ahmad-khan-and-rrr).

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you should use `RelativeLayout` inside `scrollview` and set its width and height to `match_parent`. So replace your xml code with below one

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="In order to succeed ..."
            android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and you are done...

Comment: its showing center in horizontal, but not in vertical also

Comment: make sure your `RelativeLayout` and `ScrollView` both have width and height set to `match_parent`

Comment: still same problem. I have attached screenshot after make changes as you have told http://postimg.org/image/ks3dzbuab/

Comment: see my edited answer use `android:fillViewport="true"` in `scrollview`